# Hide Headers in Passenger/Nginx Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, passenger

I am trying to hide this headers for the production server but without success :

```
 X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger (mod_rails/mod_rack) 3.0.7
 X-Runtime: 0.021429
 Server: nginx/1.0.0 + Phusion Passenger 3.0.7 (mod_rails/mod_rack)
```

Using :

```
- Rails 3.0.9
- Passenger 3.0.7
- Nginx 1.0.0
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To remove **nginx** `Server:` header you could use `server_tokens off`  [directive](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#server_tokens).

For other headers try using [Headers More](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpHeadersMoreModule#more_clear_headers) nginx module:

```
more_set_headers 'Server: anon'; # replace the default 'nginx + Passenger'
more_set_headers 'X-Powered-By'; # clear header entirely
```

Comment: *Headers More nginx* module **is not enabled** by default, you should compile it or install a specific nginx version from your OS package manager. For debian like, install the **nginx-extras**

Answer (score 0):

It possible to hide passenger headers, but require specific configuration. Something like this should work:

External world faced part:

```
upstream x {
  server your-server:8040;
}

server {
  server_name your-domain;

  # ... 
  location / {
    # ...
    proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By;
    proxy_hide_header X-Runtime;

    proxy_pass http://x;
  }
}
```

Passenger powered site:

```
server {
  server_name local-site;
  listen 8040 default_server;

  location / {
    passenger_enabled on;
    # regular site configuration
  }
}
```

`local-site` can be on same nginx with `your-domain` part, but this, probably, slight slow down request handling.